# How to print the array in swal Alert box in AnguarJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
swal({
        title: "HTML <small>Welcome to SWAL</small>!", 
        text: "A html format <span style='color:#F8BB86'>{{$scope.productArray}}<span> message.",
        html: true
    });
```

I have to print the array length in swal alert box and i am using {{$scope.productArray}} in the span but its not working for me same expression is display in swal alert,so tell me how to fix this?

swal({
        title: "HTML Welcome to SWAL!", 
        text: "A html format {{$scope.productArray}} message.",
        html: true
    });
Here $scope.productArray is an array and i have to print this array in swal?

Answer (score 2):

The template syntax will not work for js strings as far as I know, but you could use standard JS string concatenation:

```
swal({
        title: "HTML <small>Welcome to SWAL</small>!", 
        text: "A html format <span style='color:#F8BB86'>" + $scope.productArray.toString() + "<span> message.",
        html: true
    });
```

Comment: Its working sir but in the swal it will show  [object Object],[object Object]  instead of array?

Comment: How would you like it t display? You could try `JSON.stringify($scope.productArray)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
swal({
        title: "HTML <small>Welcome to SWAL</small>!", 
        text: "A html format <span style='color:#F8BB86'>
              {{ productArray }}<span> message.",
        html: true
    });
```

Comment: Its not working sir now show in alert - A html format {{ productArray }} message same text is show?